# How can I print word encoded by GBK in python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a spider in python. I got a list with one element `[u'\xb9\xd8\xd3\xda\xbf\xaa\xd5\xb9]` which is the GBK code of "关于开展". I've tried some methods, but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, an encoded string is `str` and decoded is `unicode`. The encoded `unicode` you got is caused by wrong decoding. You can convert it back to `str` by `encode('latin1')` and then decode by GBK:

```
>>> text = u'\xb9\xd8\xd3\xda\xbf\xaa\xd5\xb9'
>>> text = text.encode('latin1')
>>> text
'\xb9\xd8\xd3\xda\xbf\xaa\xd5\xb9'
>>> text = text.decode('gbk')
>>> text
u'\u5173\u4e8e\u5f00\u5c55'
```

Then you can print it.